# Use android adb shell to return one activity

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have the following problem:

Our company manufactured a android device that have no return button (not physical and not at the bottom of the screen), so I can't return to the previous activity/screen. Now I need to test an App developed by a third-party that only save settings when I return to the previous screen.

Is there any way I can return to the previous screen or emulate a user clicking the return button?

I found this to return to HOME (Android main screen):

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.HOME
```

Also read about Activity Manager and Exerciser Monkey on these links:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html

But wasn't able to solve my problem. Anybody knows how to accomplish this call using adb?

Comment: If the app doesn't save state on transitioning to home, or having another app launched replacing it, then you should fail it as broken and in need of fixing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you might want to try:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK
```

cf. [KEYCODE_BACK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_BACK) event

Comment: Perfect! That worked just as a return button. Thanks!

Comment: @ligi do you have any idea about why this doesn't work when used in a service?